# Компоненты ODAC для делфи 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Добрый день! Помогите пожалуйста люди добрые) приложение было написано на делфи 6 и работала с оракл 9, при попытке переписать на делфи 7 под оракл 10 и выше возникла проблема с ODAC а именно

```
smenap.Form1.TOraSession.SysContexts.Add('Ext.System=SOL');
smenap.Form1.TOraSession.SysContexts.Add('Ext.ARM=OERR');
smenap.Form1.TOraSession.SysContexts.Add('Ext.Ver=1.1.1.1');
smenap.Form1.TOraSession.Username := Edit1.Text;
smenap.Form1.TOraSession.Password := Password.Text;
```

Не понимает метода SysContexts, где идет проверка схемы и присваивание роли, я так понимаю в компоненте ODAC есть метод SysContexts, но почему его нету в ODAC для делфи 7?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите ту же версию компонент, только под Delphi 7.

Но все же закрадывается подозрение что это что то самописное. Такое ощущение что создается/изменяются переменные в [SYS_CONTEXT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm).

Как вариант можно раскопать старые исходники и посмотреть что там делается и написать на крайний случай [class helper](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/a/understanding-delphi-class-and-record-helpers.htm) либо если не получится - метод в который передается сессия + параметры которые нужно установить.